# install Linux on Dell Latitude D610

Tags: dell

I wanted to reuse older Window XP Dell Latitude D610 machine with Pentium M 1.8GHz processor with 512 RAM. Please advice which Linux OS would be best on this machine.

Answer (score 1):

Use Xubuntu 14.04 or Lubuntu 14.04. They use less system power and deliver good performance. Installation process is same as ubuntu. You are going to need:

1. An empty drive apart from you XP installation (min. space = 20GB
   recommended)
2. ISO image of the OS.
3. Unetbootin software and a USB drive of 2GB or more.

Install [guide](http://linoob.com/2013/10/lubuntu-13-10-released/) (process remains same):

Answer (score 0):

I happen to own a Dell 610.  I have it RIGHT HERE between my ankles as I type.  Photos available for non-believers.

It was last used to any extent last summer for training NEW USERS of ubuntu, and the operating system I was training them with was Ubuntu 12.04LTS.  It ran great, but I will add that this laptop has 2gb of ram, not 512.  However RAM for this generation of laptop is dirt cheap.  [This company](https://www.discountelectronics.com/product?product_id=4635&product_model=243?pmc=ADWPLA) sells the two 1gb memory modules it requires at only $5 each.

If the RAM could not be upgraded I could understand dissmissing this post as off-topic and telling him to install something other than moderately current versions of Ubuntu, but 12.04LTS is still supported, for now, and 14.04 will be tolerable to use once its numerous bugs are corrected.

So, to the OP, I will tell you, Please install Ubuntu 12.04LTS 32 bit and you will be most pleased.  If you need any further help installing it I'll gladly help you.

Answer (score 0):

I use Debian with Gnome classic on my older PC( AMD Sempron 2800+,512MB RAM).

You can install Xubuntu or Lubuntu or you can choose another OS like Debian, Arch, Fedora and install a lightweight desktop environment (LXDE, XFCE).

What I also tried on my older PC was to work without a desktop environment,only with a window manager. I tried WMII on a Debian Wheezy and it was nice! So, I could also recommend some window managers like WMII, Openbox etc.

After some years of using Linux I discovered that important, on older PCs to run faster, is not the Linux distribution but the desktop environment and the applications you install...